# Security Exception while connecting to Oracle Database using ojdbc6.jar

Tags: java, jdbc, ojdbc, accesscontrolexception

I have replaced **classes12.jar** to **ojdbc6.jar** to connect oracle 12c database. Here I am connecting to Service name not to SID.
This works fine if I run my applet application through eclipse as java application. 
But if I export the same application to a WAR file and deployed in weblogic it doesn't work.

I am encountering getting below exception.

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
    ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "oracle.jdbc.RetainV9LongBindBehavior" "read")
```

How to solve this exception?

Comment: Does the app. have a security manager?

Comment: What does this exact problem have to do with `swing`?

Comment: I have updated some of my **findings** , please re check my post.

Comment: Why are you not using ojdbc7.jar for 12c, which is certified for that?  Not sure if it addresses your problem.

Comment: adding `ojdbc7.jar` worked. Thank you.
Also, i added permission `java.security.AllPermission`